# Inverting interface args (x:any, y:T) to (y:T, x:any) doesn't bother TypeScript. Options?

Tags: typescript

I definded a bunch of functions according to the following interface:

```js
interface ecafretni { (x:any, y:Q): any }
```

`x` literally takes any type, there's no possible narrowing down. Think of a general-purpose deep-copy function, for example. `Q` is some other interface I defined somewhere.

Here's the problem: I had to change the order of the arguments of `ecafretni` to `(y:Q, x:any)` and I was wishing that TypeScript would point out all the (hundreds of) points where I was calling functions abiding by that interface, so that I woulnd't miss any. But it wouldn't because, of course, type `Q` is assignable to `any` and type `any` is assignable to `Q`.

So I came up with another type to use in the place of `any`: `R = Exclude<any,Q>`, and redefine `ecafretni` argument types as `(y:Q, x:R)`. But it's not working. It seems that `R` behaves the same way as `any`.

Take a look at this:

```js
const f = function( x : Exclude<any,number> ){};
const x:number = 4;
const v = f(x); // TYPE MISMATCH !!!! (not caught by TypeScript)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nitpick: `Number` is not the same as `number` - is there a reason you're using `Number` instead of `number`? Also, if you're writing a function that performs a deep-copy of JavaScript objects then you should use a dictionary type instead of `any` (and this might solve your problem too).

Comment: If you recompile with `--strict` your example program will cause an error because your `f` has an inferred return-type of `void`, which means `v = f(x);` will cause a compiler error.

Comment: The code here isn't quite a [mcve] so I'm not going to post an answer.  But I'll say that `any` is a type system escape hatch and so `[X, any]` is going to be assignable to `[any, X]` and vice versa, because `any` is basically assignable to and from anything.  And `Exclude<any, X>` doesn't work; `Exclude` only operates on unions (`any` isn't a union) and there's no negated types in TS with which to do this "the right way".  I suggest you ditch `any` and use `unknown` if you can, and then try to post a minimum reproducible example if you want a more detailed answer. Good luck!